# How do I ignore everything except a couple files in the top-level directory and everything in a few directories with .gitignore

Tags: git

I want to ignore everything except a couple files in the top-level directory and everything in a few directories with .gitignore

My top level .gitignore is:

*
!/app/
!gbase.php
!list-secret-prices.php

The problem is that I have to put a .gitignore with one entry of:

!*

in each of the subdirectories that I want to include for it to work.  I don't want to have to put a .gitignore in everyone of the directories that I want included.  I want to handle everything in the top level .gitignore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your case the following might be more appropriate:

```
/*
!app/
!gbase.php
!list-secret-prices.php
```

The first line ignores **all top-level** directories and files. Anything inside the ignored directories will also be ignored by git, even if it's not explicitly specified.

The second line unignores the `app` directory. It will also cause git to find **all** its files and subdirectories (recursively), because we never told git to ignore anything below the top-level.

Comment: Thanks molf.  The /* instead of * on the first line seems to be the key.

Answer (score 0):

I make global exclusions in my gitconfig file ($HOME/.gitconfig)

[core]
    excludesfile = /Users/meself/.gitignore

And then write my patterns in ~/.gitignore.

Would this help?